# Why should we use interface in MVP pattern for Android?

Tags: android, design-patterns, kotlin, android-mvp

I'm making an *Android* app using *Kotlin* for the first time using *MVP* pattern. My questions is, why do I need interfaces for View and Presenter as *Kotlin* provides higher order functions? Can't we just communicate using those higher order functions? Is the use of pattern without interfaces bad?

I have looked and read lots of article and tutorials but non answered my question. Is what I am doing in the code below a wrong practice? Can someone explain it to me?

In my *Activity*

```
override fun init() {

    btn_login.setOnClickListener {
        LoginPresenter.userLogin(et_emailAddress.text.toString(),et_password.text.toString()){
            if (it){
                //do something
            }else{
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Presenter

```
object LoginPresenter {

fun userLogin(emailId: String, password: String, completion: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    //do something
    completion(true)
 }
}
```

Comment: "why do I need interfaces for View and Presenter " - you don't need to use interfaces, however it's better to program to abstractions rather than implementations.  Just think how this can benefit you in unit tests, or you change the implementation - the contract stays the same . I'd argue that there is no benefit in using an interface for a presenter, just the view.  An observation, your Presenter is a singleton, it really should be scoped to the Activity.  I'm not sure your argument for the higher order functions as you could supply a `Consumer<T>` in java? Also this breaks MVP flow control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why do I need interfaces for View and Presenter as Kotlin provides higher order functions?

This is rather a common practice in software development. And while you may not use interfaces, there is a number of key points why interfaces are preferable. Off the top of my head:

1. with interface you can have multiple implementations of it without actually caring about the concrete type of the implementation. This is what you're missing with the higher order functions - you're restricted with the only type, `LoginPresenter`, when using the `LoginPresenter.userLogin()` method.
2. most of the design patterns is based on the separation of interfaces from their implementations. So programming into implementation rather than abstraction won't let you make use of those.
3. you won't be able to properly unit test classes that depend on other implementations as no mocking is possible in this case.
4. code maintenance and extension becomes much harder with concrete implementation.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Higher-order function costs**

   Kotlin official documentation on the cost of higher order functions

   > Using higher-order functions imposes certain runtime penalties: each
   >   function is an object, and it captures a closure, i.e. those variables
   >   that are accessed in the body of the function. Memory allocations
   >   (both for function objects and classes) and virtual calls introduce
   >   runtime overhead.

   and if you're replacing all your interfaces with higher-order functions, you may end up with a bad performance.

2.
 Interfaces can hold multiple functions, for which you'll need individual function params when using higher-order functions. 
Consider the following case,

```
interface UserLoginInterface {
      fun onLoginSuccess(loggedInUser: User)
      fun onLoginFailure(error: ErrorResponse)
      fun onRedirect(someOtherObjectWithDirectives: SomeDataClass)
 }
```

To translate this to higher-order functions usage, You'll have to use three Function params

Comment: Didn't knew using higher order functions could have caused bad performance.Thanks.